# How do I remove this extra span height?

Tags: css

I just stumbled upon this issue where the height of the `<span>` is greater than the font size I have set. Here it is:

```css
span {
  font-size:   36px;
  padding:     0px;
  line-height: 1;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<span>Hello world</span>
```

Even with `line-height: 1` and `padding: 0px` the span seems to get an extra 4 pixels of height. I noticed that `display: block` solves the issue but in my case that's not something practical because I need it inline.

Is there any 'trick' which would do this?

Comment: Add the letter "j" (or any letter with a descender) to the string and you will see why.

Comment: here we go again :) if you want more *strange* result, change the font-family

Comment: So the extra height is reserved for the descenders and ascenders. Well I get it. Thanks so much.

Comment: What about `display:inline-block;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `display: inline-block;`

```css
span {
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 1;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

span.last {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span>Hello world (inline-block)</span> <span class="last">Hello world (inline)</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this using css, use percentage as `line-height`. As your font have extra top and bottom space with total of `25%`, So I gave `75%` `line-height`

```css
span {
    font-size: 36px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: red;
    line-height: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>Hello world</span>
```